# How to wrap each antd table row with a `Link`?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the `Antd Table` component in `React`. I need to wrap each `row` with a `Link` component so I will be able to right click on a row and choose to open on a new tab or copy the link.

I couldn't find anything in the documentation below.
https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-dynamic-settings

Comment: Perhaps using an onClick handling function would work better in this case.  The Antd table isn't written with undocumented use cases in mind and will likely cause problems for you eventually -- even if you did get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could this be accomplished with an `onClick` instead of a link?

Here are MDN's docs on the permitted parents to a table row:

> `<table>` (only if the table has no child `<tbody>` element, and even then only after any `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, and `<thead>` elements); otherwise, the parent must be `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or `<tfoot>`

Eventually this component boils down to HTML. To echo [JuanIsFree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330489/juanisfree), you could get it to work, but breaking the rules of HTML tag nesting is not advised.

[MDN table row docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr)